# Long run multiplier equality

Tags: summation, infinity, time-series

I don't understand the following equality:

$$ \beta_0 +  \sum_{j=1}^\infty \phi^{j-1} (\phi\beta_0 + \beta_1) = \beta_0 + \frac{\phi\beta_0 + \beta_1}{1 - \phi} $$

It calculates the long run multiplier from an ADL(1,1) model.
Could someone explain it or maybe show some steps in between?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**. If $|x|<1$ then the [geometric sum evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Sum) leads to
$$
\sum_{j=1}^\infty x^{j-1}=\frac1{1-x}
$$ giving
$$
\sum_{j=1}^\infty \phi^{j-1}=\frac1{1-\phi},\qquad |\phi|<1.
$$

Comment: Thank you! I thought it had to do with geometric series, but I wasn't sure whether $ |\phi| < 1 $ was given. This doesn't apply when $ |\phi| > 1 $ right?

Comment: @BasedJohan Right, the above identity doesn't hold for $|\phi|>1$.